# Approach to determine EMI frequencies in another factory

Tags: noise, emi-filtering, spectrum-analyzer

We produce AC-powered devices that connect to PC via USB. One of which was recently shipped to a factory (which is located in another country) in an environment with high enough EMI to make our device "stuck."  It needs to be re-powered in order to function correctly again.

Our devide looks like this for reference:

[image: Electrostatic PM Mass Monitoring Technology and Field Comparison]

[Image Source](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/fig1_318942377)

We managed to re-create the issue in our lab (by re-plugging a really noisy fan to AC) and applied some of the fixes (changes cables, added AC mains filtering with GND choke etc), which helped, and reduced the issue from 2-3 "stucks" per day to 1 "stuck" per day in their factory. We decided to make a better approach to the problem to totally eliminate it, by doing one of the below:

Please correct me if I am wrong in any of the below:

- We decided that we need to know what exactly frequencies their factory produces in order to apply the correct shielding with ferrite beads for cables and foam-like absorbers (that suppresses these frequencies) to our chassis and cables. This should be done in their lab while they work, using a spectrum analyzer close to our device and we need to know the Fourier transform of the electromagnetic waves in that spot.

The question is, how do we determine these RF frequencies in a professional way, aka how is it usually done in the industry?

- Should we suggest they do the measurements if they have a spectrum analyzer? (The "stuck" of our device happens about once a day, so they should record a Fourier transform for a whole (or two) days aka 8-16 hours. They might need this spectrum analyzer for their own experiments, so this will be a discomfort for them.
- Should we send them a spectrum analyzer to make the measurements? In that case, since we do not have a spectrum analyzer, should we buy one and send it to them? They might need training to use it, and also I do not know how a spectrum analyzer can  store its data for 1-2 days. Is there an option for this? Can it be connected to a computer and store the data?
- A last option, I think, would be for us to send a representative/engineer there to do the measurements. Is this something that can be done, or is it not common? This specific factory in China is already treated as "secret-like." They don't have an internet connection in the factory, and they can't tell us what machines/other devices they use there.
- Last but not least, we are pretty sure (from tests in our lab) that the noise comes from the earth wire, which gets noisy from the around/their machines and manages to enter our device. Should the spectrum analyzer be placed close to the AC cable for that reason, or should we probe the earth cable with another approach?

Comment: Usually it might be better to improve the design, as in the end patching the design later with EMI shielding (foam etc) will take more time and money to manufacture them and will make the devices more expensive. Perhaps there is something in the schematics, PCB design, power supply, or earthing that makes it very sensitive to EMI.

Comment: @Justme well indeed we use a stepper driver that is not ours, so we cannot change its internal circuitry. This stepper driver is inside our chassis, which takes its own Power from AC, and also connects to PC via USB, it has its own USB hub inside. Unfortunately, this USB hub connects its chassis with its USB GND, and it always manages to stuck. We just buy this part, so we cannot change its PCB. We tried to open it/unscrew it once to see if we could change anything, and shield it better, but there was nothing to do

Comment: What EMC standards did you design your equipment to meet? How did you manage to meet those standards with bought in modules?

Comment: @Andyaka unfortunately, we did not test our Equipment for any EMC standards. It is not something that we have considered. But it is something that I can suggest my supervisors to do. If I suggest that, and we find out the standards that we meet, what would be the next step to solve the issue? Wouldn't we again, need to use a spectrum analyzer in their factory to find out with what frequencies we are dealing with?

Comment: The next step is decide how susceptible your equipment is to commonplace EMC standards. This may take some effort. I'm not commenting further and speculating on what ifs.

Comment: I thought you have to pass electrical safety and EMI compliance tests before selling a device. Or at least be confident that the device passes the tests. Are you sure it is legal to sell that device?

Comment: For USB wiring, you should try using a full isolated device, if there is a problem with this "ground" USB.

Comment: @Antonio51 I will give it a try thanks!

Comment: @Christianidis Vasileios   -- See this https://www.microchip.com/forums/m755613.aspx ... I tested a microchip IC, some 15 (?) years ago ... in the  "vaporized metal deposition" on glass ... because of very high power pulse ( some 10 MW @1 kV DC.

Comment: @Christianidis Vasileios -- It was a USB Bridge to pseudo "RS232c", IC used were MCP2200 and ADUM1201. https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/200022228D.pdf https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADuM1200_1201.pdf There was a kit https://www.microchip.com/en-us/development-tool/ADM00276

Comment: @Christianidis Vasileios https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/50002352A.pdf https://www.microchip.com/en-us/development-tool/ADM00276

Comment: @Christianidis Vasileios    I have found also a board EasyUSB (not isolated ! ) https://endresz.eu/easyusb/easyusb_en.html

Comment: @Antonio51 Thanks, I am checking it out!